# Java unable to import normal libraries in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

This question may be too easy for you guys, but I'm really new to java and have no idea how to solve it. I added some external libraries to my project in eclipse, which work well, but some of my normal imports show errors, and has red line under import. like:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
```

How should I solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by adding `JRE System Library`:

`Right click your project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> JRE System Library`

Answer (score 0):

First go to *windows ->preferences ->Java -> Installed JREs* and check if the JDK is checked not just a JRE.

Also Right click on the *project -> Properties -> Java Build Path ->libraries tab* and check whether the JRE System Library is present and if not.

Add it using *Add library -> JRE System Library and then select JRE for the project build path*